# Force new execution of a Report within Apex logic using ApexPages.PageReference()

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

I am executing a report to send as an email attachment in a Schedulable class.  I'm running this every day.  The problem is that it's not creating an updated version of the report each day.  It just keeps sending the same report.  Is there a way to force the re-execution of the report.  My logic is basically a Schedulable class that has this in the constructor:

```
    ApexPages.PageReference report = new ApexPages.PageReference('/00O18000000LtMY?export=1&enc=UTF-8&xf=csv');
    finalList = report.getContent().toString();
```

The execute method calls a separate class to create the email with the attachment.  I get the email each day with a csv file of the report.  It's just that it's always the same data (doesn't reflect any changes in the report).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be abandoned